# New line in bash variables

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I'm trying to store multiple lines in a bash variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

For example, if I list `/bin` one file per line and store it in `$LS`, then I pass `$LS` as stdin to `wc`, it always returns 1:

```
$ ls -1 /bin | wc -l
134
$ LS=$(ls -1 /bin); wc -l <<< $LS
1
```

If I try to output to screen, I get various results: `echo` prints all the lines on a single line, while `printf` prints only the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
LS=$(ls -1 /bin)
echo $LS
printf $LS
```

So, a bash variable can contain multiple lines?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to double quote it (and you *should* [double quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906) in most case):

```
echo "$LS"
```

But [don't use echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/38906) to print variables content, using [printf instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/38906):

```
printf '%s\n' "$LS"
```

Comment: Just to put a finer point on the overall answer: printf expects a format string to be its first parameter, which is why they didn't see what they expected. If they want to see newlines in the output from printf, arbtrarily split on spaces, `printf "%s\n" $LS` would do it.

Comment: the %LS should be $LS, btw (I couldn't make such a short edit)

Comment: Thanks! It of course works also with `wc` and other commands: `wc -l <<< "$LS"`

Comment: @JeffSchaller: No, you shouldn't unquote variable in this case, just using `printf '%s\n' "$LS"` if you want to see newline. That's mis-typing, fixed it!

Comment: Why shouldn't you use echo to print variables ?

Comment: @User112638726 - see the linked article

Comment: @JeffSchaller Oh, didn't even see the links!

Comment: i don't think this works -- in my case, i'm saving `$(git diff)`, which has mentions of `\n` that I've added, which subsequently get interpreted as a newline by [`echo`](http://bxr.su/o/bin/echo/echo.c).

Comment: oh, so, not too surprisingly, the solution is to use [`printf`](http://bxr.su/o/usr.bin/printf/printf.c) instead of echo, as echo makes no distinction between actual newlines and \n literals.  `V=$(printf 'line1:test\\ntest\\n\nline2\n') ; printf '%s\n' "$V"`

Answer (score 9):

The newlines are in the variable. `LS=$(ls -1)` sets the variable `LS` to the output of `ls -1` (which produces the same output as `ls`, by the way, except when the output goes to a terminal), minus trailing newlines.

The problem is that you're removing the newlines when you print out the value. In a shell script, `$LS` does not mean “the value of the variable `LS`”, it means “take the value of `LS`, split it into words according to `IFS` and interpret each word as a glob pattern”. To get the value of `LS`, you need to write `"$LS"`, or more generally to put `$LS` between double quotes.

`echo "$LS"` prints the value of `LS`, except in some shells that interpret backslash characters, and except for a few values that begin with `-`.

`printf "$LS"` prints the value of `LS` as long as it doesn't contain any percent or backslash character and (with most implementations) doesn't start with `-`.

To print the value of `LS` exactly, use `printf %s "$LS"`. If you want a newline at the end, use `printf '%s\n' "$LS"`.

Note that `$(ls)` is not, in general, the list of files in the current directory. This only works when you have sufficiently tame file names. To get the list of file names (except dot files), you need to use a wildcard: `*`. The result is a list of strings, not a string, so you can't assign it to a string variable; you can use an array variable `files=(*)` in shells that support them (ksh93, bash, zsh).

For more information, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: printf "$LS" would also succumb to backslash character parsing, similar to echo

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned

```
printf '%s\n' "$LS"
```

is the only correct solution.

Let me demonstrate that the other proposed solutions, both with [`echo`](http://bxr.su/o/bin/echo/echo.c) and [`printf`](http://bxr.su/o/usr.bin/printf/printf.c), simply do not work properly:

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ touch \\n
$ LS=$(ls -l)
$ echo "$LS"
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 domain  domain  0 Nov  5 06:12

$ printf "$LS\n"
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 domain  domain  0 Nov  5 06:12

$ printf '%s\n' "$LS"
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 domain  domain  0 Nov  5 06:12 \n
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 domain  domain  0 Nov  5 06:12 \n
$ rm \\n
$ cd ..
$ rmdir t
$
```

(One can also test with `V=$(printf 'line0:\\n\\n\nline1.\n') printf '%s\n' "$V"` and variations.)

Whereas `\n` in the filenames may not be that common, store [`git diff`](http://ports.su/devel/git) into a variable, and your chances of encountering literal `\n` increase dramatically.

Comment: Note that `ksh` and `zsh` also support `print -r -- "$LS"` and `zsh` also has `echo -E - $LS`. `csh` has `echo $LS:q` though  that doesn't output the newline character if $LS is empty, and getting a multiline value into $LS in the first place is quite tricky in csh.