# format output with what?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

I'm trying to format the output from the following command;

```
MYIP=(/sbin/ifconfig $(getnic) | awk '/inet/ { print $2 } ' | sed -e s/addr://); echo $MYIP
```

which generates the following output;

> 172.30.0.1 fe80::42:c5ff:fecd:f09f 172.31.0.1 fe80::42:47ff:fe57:2f0d 172.17.0.1 fe80::42:a1ff:fe4e:2508 127.0.0.1 ::1 fe80::2887:fcff:fe19:e54b fe80::bc99:3aff:fe46:dcab
>   fe80::b090:4cff:fecb:3dc4 fe80::9c0f:6dff:fe6b:6c71
>   fe80::808f:5fff:febb:2669 fe80::f851:23ff:fee4:c87a
>   fe80::4c97:24ff:fe04:ea02 fe80::4cde:e2ff:feb7:4784
>   fe80::c4fc:4aff:fe67:1863 192.168.1.134 fe80::d1f1:947f:9370:74ca

How do I make it look nicer, 
just with each ipadress on a separate line?

**Edit**: *clarification*; for now I just want all ip's on a separate line, one each. Would be noce to strip out the v6 numbers, but htatäs really not important. Would be a bonux though.

I've tried with tr, sed, awk but I guess I'm doing something wrong or using the wrong command. My thought was just to add another pipe at the end that does some kind of word wrangling magic.

EDIT:
This is the complete function;

```
function myip() {
    MY_IP=$(/sbin/ifconfig $(getnic) | awk '/inet / { print $2 } ' | sed -e s/addr://| sort)
    echo -e ${MY_IP:-"Not connected"}
}
```

But it still won't print linebreaks. Working on that. Thanx for all input

Comment: Change the last command to this: `echo -e "$MYIP\n"`

Comment: @b0red Which do you want? Each IPv4 address on a separate line with the IPv6 addresses following, or each IPv4 AND IPv6 address on its own line?  Please click [edit] and enhance the question to tell us. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Hahaha. Damn. Thank you. Easy when you think outside the box :)

Comment: Can't be in the box, my cat beat me to it. OBTW, use tr to replace each space with a newline, for the mixed IPv4/v6 solution.  Then, for the IPv4 only solution, delete each line which has a colon in it.

Comment: Your command doesn't do what you say it does. It's missing at least a `$` for command substitution. Please show the actual command. And use code formatting for the output, please

Comment: Probably related: [New line in bash variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214858/new-line-in-bash-variables)

Comment: If you want only ipv4 addresses, change the regex in awk to `/inet /` (i.e. with a space).   If you want to print MYIP with all its embedded spaces, then you need to double-quote it when you use it - e.g. `echo "$MYIP"` instead of `echo $MYIP`.   Also, the command-substitution should be double-quoted too: `MYIP="$(...)"`.   See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Include the expected output with your question.

Comment: You want to quote your sed-statement: `sed -e 's/addr://'` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of the command string you now have:

```
| tr ' ' '\n'
```

which replaces the space character with a newline.

Comment: tried that, but that doesn't work for me somehow.

Comment: Please grab the source file, upload it to a site like pastebin.com and put its URL in your question, and I will take a whack at it later (I hope), so someone with brains will  (...braiiiiins.....)

Comment: It works now. Thanxfor all help

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `echo`-statement with

```bash
printf '%s\n' ${MY_IP:-"Not connected"}
```

and you should be good.

`printf` will evaluate the format-string `'%s\n'` for all its args and thus print a newline after each string you feed it.

Comment: Thanx. This worked fine!

Comment: You can follow up with grep to get rid of the ipv6-adresses: `| grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'`